# Several WordPress sites to share plugin data

Tags: wordpress

I am wondering if there is a way to have two WordPress installations with separate databases or table prefixes, but install a plugin and use data generated by it on both websites.

For example, if I hade website1.com and website2.com. Website1 has `s1` table prefix, Website2 has `s2`. At this point, they are still two separate websites.

Now, I'd like to install a plugin which, of course, comes with its own set of tables and whatnot. Is there a way to share that data between these two websites? Make `s2` point to `s1` tables just for this purpose, or create a third prefix and point both websites to it?

Or is there a completely different approach I'm not thinking of? Is this at all possible?

Comment: Possible? Yes, absolutely. The plugin could create its own database table and both sites would need to query this table to get whatever data they need from it. Is this the answer you're looking for?

Comment: @cabrerahector it's a part of the answer, yeah. It's good to know it can be done, but that still means I don't know how to do it :) every article I find is about MultiSite, which doesn't work for me.

Comment: The how-to-do-it part is up to you. Writing a plugin that creates a database table isn't difficult (in your case, you don't want it to use the prefix of either of your sites to make it evident that this plugin's database table is site-independent). Check the official documentation, there's a working example there on how to create a database table on plugin activation. Now, having your two sites get data from it is where the fun begins and that is also up to you to sort out. The [$wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) object will be useful in this particular case.

Comment: And yes, you can have two WordPress sites share the same database without using multisite. Make sure both setups are on separate folders and that each site uses their own database table prefix and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks! Feel free to write an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: No problem, done, and good luck! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible? Yes, absolutely. The plugin could create its own database table and both sites would need to query this table to get whatever data they need from it.

The how-to-do-it part is up to you. Writing a plugin that creates a database table isn't difficult (in your case, you don't want it to use the prefix of either of your sites to make it evident that this plugin's database table is site-independent). Check the official documentation, there's a working example there on how to create a database table on plugin activation. Now, having your two sites get data from it is where the fun begins and that is also up to you to sort out. The [$wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) object will be useful in this particular case.

And yes, you can have two WordPress sites share the same database without using multisite. Just make sure both setups are on separate folders and that each site uses their own database table prefix and you're good to go.

Happy coding!